# Data Vault 2 - Hash diff and recurring data changes

Tags: database, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-vault

I am having issues retrieving the latest value in a satellite table when some data is changed back to a former value.

The database is Snowflake.

As per Data Vault 2.0, I am currently using the hash diff function to assess whether to insert a new record in a satellite table, like this:

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SAT_ACCOUNT_DETAILS AD WHERE AD.MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT = MD5_Account AND AD.HASH_DIFF = AccHashDiff) = 0
  THEN
    INTO SAT_ACCOUNT_DETAILS (MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT
                            , HASH_DIFF
                            , ACCOUNT_CODE
                            , DESCRIPTION
                            , SOME_DETAIL
                            , LDTS)
    VALUES (MD5_AE_Account
          , AccHashDiff
          , AccountCode
          , Description
          , SomeDetail
          , LoadDTS)
SELECT DISTINCT
    MD5(AccountId) As MD5_Account
  , MD5(UPPER(COALESCE(TO_VARCHAR(AccountCode), '')
    || '^' || COALESCE(TO_VARCHAR(Description), '')
    || '^' || COALESCE(TO_VARCHAR(SomeDetail), '')
    )) AS AccHashDiff
  , AccountCode
  , Description
  , SomeDetail
  , LoadDTS
FROM source_table;
```

The first time, a new record with *AccountCode* = '100000' and *SomeDetail* = 'ABC' is added:

| MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT | HASH_DIFF | ACCOUNT_CODE | DESCRIPTION | SOME_DETAIL | LDTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c81e72... | 8d9d43... | 100000 | An Account | ABC | 2021-04-08 10:00 |

An hour later, an update changes the value of *SomeDetail* to 'DEF', this is the resulting table:

| MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT | HASH_DIFF | ACCOUNT_CODE | DESCRIPTION | SOME_DETAIL | LDTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c81e72... | 8d9d43... | 100000 | An Account | ABC | 2021-04-08 10:00 |
| c81e72... | a458b2... | 100000 | An Account | DEF | 2021-04-08 11:00 |

A third update sets the value of *SomeDetail* back to 'ABC', but the record is **not inserted** in the satellite table, because the value of the hash diff is the same as the first inserted record (i.e. 8d9d43...).

If I query which is the latest record in the satellite table, the LDTS column tells me it's the one with 'DEF' which is not the desired result.
Instead, I should have a record with *SomeDetail* = 'ABC' and *LDTS* = '2021-04-08 12:00'.

What is the correct approach to this? If I add *LoadDTS* to the hash diff, a new record will be created each time an update is pushed, which is not the desired result either.

Comment: for our SCD2 pipeline, we hash the values, but also have a `_is_current` which is true only for the current row, thus we only compare the _current_ row's hashes, when injecting altered data. It does mean you have to alter that row when you do the insert, which I don't recall the pattern of.

Comment: _If I query which is the latest record in the satellite table, the LDTS column tells me it's the one with 'DEF'_ But that **is** the latest record? If you compare your incoming record to the latest record it will be different (although with hash there is always a low chance it will not be different)

Answer (score 2):

As you (and also the standard) mentionned, you need to compare to the last effective record.

I'm not an expert with Snowflake, but it might look like this :

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SAT_ACCOUNT_DETAILS AD WHERE AD.MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT = MD5_Account AND AD.HASH_DIFF = AccHashDiff AND AD.LDTS = (SELECT MAX(LDTS) FROM SAT_ACCOUNT_DETAILS MAD WHERE MAD.MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT = AD.MD5_HUB_ACCOUNT)) = 0
  THEN ....
```

By adding "AD.LDTS = (SELECT MAX(LDTS) FROM....." to the query, you make sure you test against the latest data and not historical data